# Getting user input till I meet a condition in python

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.5

I'm trying to write a code where the program keeps getting the user input in integers and adds it to an empty array. As soon as the user enters "42", the loop stops and prints all the collected values so far.

Ex:
**Input:**

```
1
2
3
78
96
42
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 78 96
```

Here is my code (which isn't working as expected):

```
num = []

while True:
  in_num = input("Enter number")
  if in_num == 42:
    for i in num:
      print (i)
    break
  else:
    num.append(in_num)
```

Comment: you have to convert the input to `int`eger because by default, it is a string.

Comment: Use this `in_num = int(input("Enter number"))`

Comment: `in_num` is a string, you can't compare strings to numbers. Since you want to stop when the user inputs the string "42" your test should do that, rather than comparing to the integer object 42.

Comment: You get a string when you do `input`. Cast it to an int like `in_num = int(input('Enter number'))`

Comment: or just do this `if in_num == "42":`

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution, which also catches errors when integers are not entered as inputs:

```
num = []

while True:
    try:
        in_num = int(input("Enter number"))
        if in_num == 42:
            for i in num:
                print(i)
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter a valid number!')
        continue
    else:
        num.append(in_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the if condition: Input builtin function returns a string and you are comparing it with an integer.

```
in_num = None    
num = []    

while True:
    in_num = input("Enter number: ")
    if in_num == "42": #or you could use int(in_num)
        for i in num:
            print(i)
        break
    else:
        num.append(in_num)
```

Comment: probably every possible answer is in the comments now. This does not add anything new. -1

Comment: Maybe I was answering and had to do some work in the meanwhile?

Comment: You should not do like this. OP clearly saying he want to add input in `integers`. he may want to do some thing with that array. in my opinion it will mislead the OP because string and integers difference is there.

Comment: If you wait 16 mins for answering a question then someone else will answer it. Either way the question is not good

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that `input` is giving you a string and you check in `line 5` for an `int`.
You have to replace it to `if in_num == "42"` or directly convert your `input("Enter number")` to an int using `int(input("Enter number"))`

Comment: why convert a string to a string ????

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for mentioning! Meant to convert it to an integer. Corrected my answer